# Add string to file content

Tags: vb.net, file, uwp

I try to open a file and add a string to the existing content by the following code in UWP

```
Public Async Sub AddDataToFile(sFileName As String, sStructData As String)
    Dim storageFolder As StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim sampleFile As StorageFile = Await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(sFileName)

    Dim text As String = Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile)
    text += sStructData
    Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, text)

End Sub
```

Unfortunately I throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.

at the method `ReadTextAsync()`. Why that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Windows.Storage.StorageFile fileToRead =
                    await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("File.txt");
                    string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(fileToRead);

                        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(fileToRead, "text Goes HERE" + text );
```

I think this is what you need

Comment: I just wrote my working code as your code worked fine for me on my VS ..just keep in mind...Every time you write a file the previous text in the file gets erased, though the file initially has something in it but if you write an empty text while again writing to the file , reading it will return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code snippet on my side and it worked well. There is nothing wrong with your `AddDataToFile`  method. So the possible reason may be something wrong with the file you invoked for reading. Since you can `GetFileAsync` successfully, so the file may be actually existed. Then you got `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` at `ReadTextAsync()` method, this may lead by you don't have permissions to access this file, maybe this file is created by other users that you cannot access, or maybe file is accessed by another process for writing.

You can create a file in the local folder by yourself and read and write again, it should work. Since you didn't provide the code for invoking this method, so here I complete the code to invoke the method with a file new created, and it can work well. Code as follows:

```
Private Async Sub btnreadandwrite_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim storageFolder As StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim sampleFile As StorageFile = Await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sampleFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
    Await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "inital text")
    AddDataToFile("sampleFile.txt", "add new content")
End Sub

Public Async Sub AddDataToFile(sFileName As String, sStructData As String)
    Dim storageFolder As StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim sampleFile As StorageFile = Await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(sFileName)
    Dim text As String = Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile)
    text += sStructData
    Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, text)
End Sub
```